# How to say "Which city are you from?"

Tags: grammar, translation, word-usage, word-choice

How do you say "Which city are you from?"  Which one below is correct? Are there any other new sentences I can use?

어느 도시에 사세요?

어디 도시에 사세요?

어디에 도시 사세요?

Comment: Small nitpick: "어느 도시에 사세요?" means "Which city do you live in?", that is, the current place of residence. E.g., if I grew up in Seoul but currently live in Paris, my answer to the question will be Paris.

Answer (score 1):

- 어느 도시에 사세요? => Correct and recommended way.
- 어디 도시에 사세요? =>  Incorrect (or borderline correct?).  It's grammatically questionable but sometimes people say it like this.
  (The meaning is more like 어디의 도시에 사세요? (we usually drop the possessive 의), which is like saying "City in which area/location (of the country/world) are you from?".  You can think of it as equivalent to 어디에 있는 도시에 사세요?)
- 어디에 도시 사세요? => This is incorrect and makes no sense at all.